# force apache2 to redirect http directory to https

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I don't understand because this code does not run. foldername is a real folder in /var/www, apache2 runs but browser does not redirect that directory forcing SSL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foldername/.\*
RewriteRule ^(.\*)$ https://host.name.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Is /var/www the DocumentRoot?

Comment: Safado: thanks for reply. Yep: /var/www

Comment: OK, just checking. Typically I've seen /var/www as the ServerRoot, but never really the DocumentRoot, which if that were the case the REQUEST_URI condition would need some adjustments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might have the regular expressions mixed up a bit. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foldername/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://host.name.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Is it possible not to use "host.name.com" (eg something like RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R,L])?

Comment: Seems that last line (RewriteRule) has ignored...

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape the '*' with a '\'.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foldername/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://host.name.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: https://host.com.com$1 is https://example1.org$1? I've done your fix but again does not run :-/ thanks